# Load script in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this URL which I want to load as as script tag in a Chrome Extension.

I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

and this:

```
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
    document.body.appendChild(s);
```

either way, I get this error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

my manifest.json file entry looks like so:

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

**is there any way to include a script tag referencing a www url?**

Comment: I admittedly don't work with Chrome extensions much, but isn't `script-src 'self';` limiting you to only being allowed to include local scripts? Would just removing that allow external scripts?

Comment: yeah I tried that, thinking along the same lines, and I got another error, let me try that again

Comment: Try the flag --allow-running-insecure-content

Comment: *Where* are you trying to do this? Background page? Content-script?

Comment: In the Extension, which is supposedly the same as the background script

Comment: Where you wish to load this script tag? in user's web page or popup html file?